# Traversing list of nodes, this = this.next does not work in java?

Tags: java, list, linked-list, this

```
public class node { 
         int data ;
         node next = null ;  

         public node(int newdata){
         data = newdata ;
         next = null ;
         }  

         public void attach(int newdata){
             node list = this ;         
             {
                 while(this.next != null){
                     System.out.println("---------------------------------------") ;                     
                     list = this.next ;                                      
                     //this = this.next ;  WHY CAN'T i DO THIS?
                 }
                 this.next = new node(newdata) ;                 
             }           
         }
```

The code above has a bug: it does not advance to the next node, because this = this.next does not work:
"the left hand-side of the assignment must be a variable".

My solution is to have variable node "list" pointing to**this** node. Then traverse it as usual:

```
public void attach2(int newdata){
                 node list = this ;         
                 {
                     while(list.next != null){
                         System.out.println("---------------------------------------") ;                     
                         list = list.next ;                                      
                         //this = this.next ;  WHY CAN'T i DO THIS?

                     }
                     list.next = new node(newdata) ;// put new value as a node to end of list
                 }           
             }
```

**Is there better way? can I avoid using 'current' and solely using this keyword?**

Comment: No I am pretty sure you cannot avoid a "current" variable which I would keep track of in an outer class called "Tree".

Answer (score 2):

`this` is reserved [java keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) which points current instance, you can not use this as variable, so `this = this.next;` is syntactical error.